# Dynamic parallel pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins DSL pipeline where I create dynamical some `steps`, and I was wondering how can I run all the steps in `parallel`.

Since I use `script` to split the string into array an iterate, `parallel` seems to complain, since it has to be between `stage` tags

Here a code example

```
    stages {
        stage('BuildAll') {
                script {
                    parallel {
                        "${names}".split(",").each { name->
                            stage(name) {
                                sh "env | grep -i NODE_NAME"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are running the `parallel` function inside the `script` directive you must use the scripted syntax for the parallel function:

> Takes a map from branch names to closures and an optional argument failFast which > will terminate all branches upon a failure in any other branch:
>
> ```
>    parallel firstBranch: {
>        // do something
>    }, secondBranch: {
>        // do something else
>    },
>    failFast: true|false
> ```

So you can use the [collectEntries](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.8.9/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)) method to iterate over your list and generate the Map that will be passed to the parallel function. Something like:

```groovy
stages {
    stage('BuildAll') {
        steps {
            script {
                parallel names.split(',').collectEntries { name ->
                    ["Execution ${name}": {   // Map key is the branch name
                        // Following code will be executed in parallel for each branch
                        stage(name) {
                            sh "env | grep -i NODE_NAME"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to define the map and then call parallel:

```groovy
stages {
    stage('BuildAll') {
        steps {
            script {
                def executions = names.split(',').collectEntries { name ->
                    ["Execution ${name}": {
                        stage(name) {
                            sh "env | grep -i NODE_NAME"
                        }
                    }]
                }
                parallel executions
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks fore the answer. Both options return this error: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "BuildAll" @ line 76, column 13.
               stage('BuildAll') {
               ^

Comment: @paul correct! there was a missing steps directive - I updated the examples.